# Iframe embed not working

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I have iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.keyshot.com/vr/keyshot6/motox/motox.html" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

And on the browser, it doesn't appear ? Is there a mistake or i can use the other way to embed [this](https://www.keyshot.com/vr/keyshot6/motox/motox.html) code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake, have a look at the console:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.keyshot.com/vr/keyshot6/motox/motox.html' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

which means you cannot access this site via an iframe from another website.

Comment: How can i add this 360 image into my website. Thank you !